# Exports is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I'm trying to produce an Angular app based on my first app, which gives me some trouble.

Here's what I've got:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>FiveRX 2.0 Management</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

    <!-- Dependencies -->
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>

    <!-- Init Application -->
    <script src="/app/config/system.config.js"></script>
    <script src="/app/config/system.init.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    <div class="title">Troubleshooting</div>
</div>
<layout></layout>
</body>
</html>
```

system.config.js

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            "npm:": "node_modules/"
        },

        map: {
            "app": "app",
            "@angular/core": "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
            "@angular/common": "npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js",
            "@angular/compiler": "npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js",
            "@angular/platform-browser": "npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js",
            "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js",
            "@angular/http": "npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js",
            "@angular/router": "npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js",
            "@angular/forms": "npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js",
            "@angular/animations": "npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js",
            "@angular/animations/browser": "npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js",
            "@angular/platform-browser/animations": "npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js",
            "rxjs": "npm:rxjs",
        },
        packages: {

            app: {
                main: "bootstrap.js"
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: "js"
            },
            scripts: {
                format: "register",
                defaultExtension: "js",
                scriptLoad: true
            }
        },
        meta: {
            "*": {
                authorization: true
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

system.init.js

```
System.import('app')
    .catch(function(err) {
         console.error(err);
    });
```

bootstrap.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "lib": [ "es5", "es6", "es2015", "dom" ]
    }
}
```

As you see, the bootstrap file doesn't contain anything but an import of platform-browser-dynamic. I get the following error when I try to run this:

```
Error: exports is not defined
  Evaluating http://localhost:55549/app/bootstrap.js
  Loading app
    at eval (:55549/app/bootstrap.js:2)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at _e (evaluate.js:106)
    at instantiate.js:414
    at R (register-loader.js:684)
    at E (register-loader.js:631)
    at O (register-loader.js:540)
    at register-loader.js:128
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:365)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:125)
    at zone.js:760
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:165)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:593)
    at <anonymous>
```

Now, I can get this to work by targetting ES6 instead of ES5, but that's neither an explanation nor an option.
Any ideas what's up here?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question but - if you're just starting with Angular, I'd seriously recommend using the [CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/) rather than trying to configure everything manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into a rather peculiar situation.

With your configuration, `tsc` will compile modules to the CommonJS format, which is the default if your target is *not* `es6`. So your `bootstrap.ts` code compiles to this JavaScript:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
//# sourceMappingURL=bootstrap.js.map
```

SystemJS is normally able to recognize that a module is a CommonJS module and will automatically provide an execution environment suitable for this case. **Unfortunately, the generated code above is not enough to get SystemJS to recognize that your module is in the CommonJS format** and so it default to its native module format and fails on `Object.defineProperty` because `exports` does not exist.

In the code above, you'll notice that there is no `require` call that corresponds to your `import` statement. That's because `tsc` detects that there is no need for a `require` call at runtime, and thus does not emit it. If you just change your TypeScript code to this, then `tsc` will emit a `require` call (otherwise the `platformBrowserDynamic()` call would fail) and SystemJS can detect the module format:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

platformBrowserDynamic();
```

In cases where SystemJS is still unable to detect the format, remember that you can use the [`format` option](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/module-formats.md) in your SystemJS configuration to tell SystemJS to use a specific format.

When you change the target to `es6`, the default module format changes to `es6` too, which explains why you don't get that error anymore.